# Как в Laravel удалить куки?

Tags: php, laravel

Как в Laravel удалить куки?
Задаю куки вот так:

```
$value = $request->cookie('name','Dron');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return redirect('/')->withCookie(Cookie::forget('name'));
```